# Gradle: Adding variant Jars as Dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have 5 `productFlavors`, of which each has their own jar dependency that I need to add when building. Everywhere I've searched, people say to add the following to dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    //Third party jars
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

However, this seems to execute before each jar is created so it doesn't successfully compile anything until I run the build process for a second time.  Here is how I build the jars:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        /** Lets build our thrift tasks for each productFlavor **/

        //Find pre-existing buildThrift task or create new one
        def String taskName = "buildThrift${variant.productFlavors[0].name}"
        def Task buildThrift = tasks.findByName(taskName)
        if (!buildThrift) {
            buildThrift = task "$taskName"(type: Exec) {
                workingDir rootDir
                commandLine './thrift-gen.sh'
            }
        }
        variant.javaCompile.dependsOn(buildThrift)
    }
```

What am I missing? Or is my idea here not even possible to get working?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are creating jar files programmatically and want to add the same in build.gradle on runtime. If this is the case, it seems it is not possible, as when the gradle project is build, it compiles all the dependencies.

As an alternative, you need to create the jars separately and then add them to your gradle project.

Hope this help you.

Thanks
Anurag